# como traer un valor en especifico siendo otro valor mayor con php y mysql

Tags: php, mysql

tengo mi siguiente consulta y estoy usando PHP y MYSQL:

```
  $a=$datosone['a'];
  $r=$datosone['r'];
  $c=$datosone['c'];
  $s=$datosone['s'];


$cond=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from `especial` order by abs(a - $a), abs(r - $r), abs(c - $c) LIMIT 1");
    $condicione = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cond);
    
    $rad=$condicione['rad'];
```

Antes de esto estoy usando un formulario común y corriente en donde ingreso los valores de a,r,c

Lo que estoy haciendo en la consulta es que por medio de los valores de a,r,c busque en la tabla 'especial' y me traiga otro valor de acuerdo a los valores ya ingresados anteriormente de a,r,c.

Ahora la condición es que debe traer el valor final que es igual a la variable $rad. pero solo debe traerlo con el valor mayor entre a,r,c.

Como podría hacer esto?

Cualquier ayuda me seria de gran utilidad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segun te entiendo quiere traer el valor mayor de tu bd en base a tus datos a, r, c.

Supongo que deberias evaluar desde php cual es el valor mayor y la consulta con ese valor

```php
if( $a > $r && $a > $c ){
    // realizas tu consulta en base a "a"
}else if( $r > $a && $r > $c ){
        // realizas tu consulta en base a "r"
}else{
      // Caso contrario c debe ser mayor y la realizas en base a "c"
}
```

Comment: Hola @Carlos López, muchas gracias por tu ayuda. entonces la consulta dentro del if quedaria asi? $one=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from `especial` where tamano='$tam' AND zona='$zon' order by abs(a - $a) LIMIT 1");
 $on = mysqli_fetch_assoc($one);
 
 $rad=$on['rad'];

Comment: Listo, ya me funciono perfecto con tu solución, si era lo que quería. muchas gracias.

Comment: Ok, que bueno, saludos!